# Unable to Insert Data to Database with VB.NET

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, command, bunifu

I have tried everything, but without success. connection variable is assigned to my database Url.

Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub GunaButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GunaButton1.Click
    'MySQL query string

    Dim command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `Register`(`Username`, `Password`) VALUES (@usr,@pw,)", Connection)

    ' Command parameters
    command.Parameters.Add("@usr", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BunifuMaterialTextbox3.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@pw", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BunifuMaterialTextbox4.Text

    Connection.Open()

    If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR")
    End If
End Sub
```

The error it's giving me:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1'

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that you have an error in your SQL syntax and it appears that you have not bothered to check your SQL syntax. You have a spurious comma in your value list.  `VALUES (@usr,@pw,)` should be `VALUES (@usr,@pw)`.